# Figaro Gem Config Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to setup Figaro in Rails 4, but after setting up the correctly yaml as such

application.yml

```
aws_access_key_id:'#' 
aws_secret_access_key:'#' 
fog_directory:'#'
```

CarrierWave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|                       
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:               "AWS",                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV["aws_access_key_id"],                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key:    ENV["aws_secret_access_key"],                           # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["fog_directory"]                          # required

end
```

I keep getting this error

```
`global_configuration': undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x007f9c7a0d9a80> (NoMethodError)
```

I've looked into similar problems but haven't found the right answer, the YAML worked on http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: You say `app.yml` but you mean `application.yml`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaml file is super sensitive and even though it passed on http://www.yamllint.com/, there was a formatting error it didn't catch